# Calling a constant by a backreference with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

```
$so = file_get_contents(...) ;
$so = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/e", constant(\1), $so) ;
```

trying to replace text between asterisks with constants of the same name but I keep getting an
unexpected T_LNUMBER. What am I writing wrong? I verified the existence of $so as a string, and all the constants exist as they are plain text.

I probably won't use this script but I was curious what I'm messing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how the code is evaluated.

The line:

```
preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/e", constant(\1), $so) ;
```

Should be:

```
$so = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/e", "constant('\\1')", $so) ;
```

You need to enclose the value passed to `constant()` in quotes so it is treated as a string.  Furthermore, enclose the second argument in quotes so the backreferences are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. I doubt Ill go with this script but you answered exactly what I was trying to find out.

Comment: @MagicLasso If you choose this route, you can use `$1` instead of `\\1` (IMO it's cleaner). You should probably use `preg_replace_callback()` though (read comments on other answers).

Answer (score 5):

Try `preg_replace_callback("/\*([^*]+)\*/e", create_function('$matches','return constant($matches[1]);'), $so)`

I've always suspected there were anonymous functions in php, but I've never had to use them. Here is the nicer:

```
preg_replace_callback("/\*([^*]+)\*/e", function($matches){
    return constant($matches[1]);
}, $so)
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments below, the \e modifier is unnecessary once you are using a callback, because we don't need to evaluate any code in the returned value.

Comment: Thief :P. Btw: you don’t need the /e flag anymore. It doesn’t have any use in that context

Comment: I upvoted. Good explanation wasnt too sure if the e flag was still considered good practice.

Comment: The [manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) that the use of the `e` modifier has been "discouraged" due to security concerns (cc @MagicLasso)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do that is:

```
$so = preg_replace_callback("/\*([^*]+)\*/", function($m){return constant($m[1])}, $so);
```

Your `constant(\1)` doesn’t make any sense in php.

Comment: +1 for correctness; but note that this only works on PHP > 5.3.0 since it uses [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: works perfect, except a semicolon is missing, so better : function($m){return constant($m[1]);}

Answer (score 0):

You should replace with `$1`, `\1` is better used for backreference, as you said, but in the same regex.

Answer (score 0):

T_LNUMBER referrers to your variable. You can't name a variable starting with a number.
[php codex](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: How does this answer 'what Im messing up' ?